# Google Script cell value email notification by current date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to send automated email notifications from my google spreadsheet if the value in column E is higher than 0. [The spreadsheet looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftpIF.png). The problem is I cant figure out how to check only values for current days date and then post by email. My code looks like this

```js
  var failedOperationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("notif").getRange("E2"); 
  var failedOperation = failedOperationRange.getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  // Check totals sales
  
    
  if (failedOperation > 0){
   // ui.alert('Failed operation occured!');
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = failedOperation; 
    var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';

    for(var i in TO) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(TO[i], subject, message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value for the corresponding row in column 'H' and compare it with a javascript Date object.
If you need the current date in a string format you can use this:

```
var today = new Date();
today.toLocaleDateString(); // 3/26/2020
```

Then you send the email if the two conditions (failed operations > 0 and date = today) are satisfied.